# Javascript function not firing and console not offering any insight

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know what is wrong with this code JS code? The function does not fire and console isn't offering any insight. This was working in the click function with minor changes but not in its own function.

```js
    //History Chart
    $expanded = true;
    var $parent;

    function graphShowHide(parent) {
        $parent = parent;
        if ($expanded) {
            $('#ExpandedGraphRow').hide("fast", function() {
            });
            if($('body').innerWidth() < 673) {
                $('div.nbs-flexisel-nav-left, div.nbs-flexisel-nav-right').css('top', '415px');
                $(parent).find('#ExpandedGraphRow').css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    bottom: '0'
                });
                $(parent).find('.animation-wrapper').animate({
                    height: '397px'},
                    200, function() {
                });
            }
            setTimeout(function($) {
                $(parent).find('.history-bar-wrapper').width('100%');
            }, 200);
            $(parent).find('h4 img').hide('fast');
            $(parent).find('h4 span').width('100%').css('float', 'none');
            $expanded = false;
            $(this).text('show history');
        } else {
            var currentWidth = $(parent).find('h4').width();
            var nthChild = $(parent).index();
            if($('body').innerWidth() > 982 && nthChild == 2) {
                $('.nbs-flexisel-nav-right').trigger('click');
            } else if($('body').innerWidth() < 983 && nthChild == 1) {
                $('.nbs-flexisel-nav-right').trigger('click');
            }
            $(parent).find('h4 span, .history-bar-wrapper').width(currentWidth);
            $(parent).find('h4 span').css('float', 'left');
            $(parent).find('h4 img').show('slow');
            $('#ExpandedGraphRow').show("slow", function() {
            });
            if($('body').innerWidth() < 673) {
                $('div.nbs-flexisel-nav-left, div.nbs-flexisel-nav-right').css('top', '748px');
                $(parent).find('#ExpandedGraphRow').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    bottom: '66px'
                });
                $(parent).find('.animation-wrapper').animate({
                    height: '729px'},
                    200, function() {
                    
                });
            }
            $(this).text('hide history');
            $expanded = true;
        }
    }

    $('.history-button').click(graphShowHide('.BMI'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you post your html/css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.history-button').click(function() {
    graphShowHide('.BMI');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function, not binding it to the click. Wrap the call in another function for it to work correctly:

```
$('.history-button').click(function() {
    graphShowHide('.BMI');
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

Comment: Hah, I just finished typing out the same thing! Oh, well, I will delete mine and upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line:

```
$('.history-button').click(graphShowHide('.BMI'));
```

By this one:

```
$('.history-button').click(function() { graphShowHide('.BMI') });
```